# How can I find Smart contract address deployed in sepolia testnet?

Tags: contract-deployment, uniswapv3, sepolia

I'm finding contract address of SwapRouter and Quoter which is the contract of uniswap version 3.
Of course Goerli address is in uniswap doc. But I want to know the address in sepolia.
If anybody know that, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Uniswap isnt deployed on sepolia, afaik

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I found address of UniswapV2Router02 contract in 0xB26B2De65D07eBB5E54C7F6282424D3be670E1f0 from sepolia testnet.
And I need address of SwapRouter and Quoter contract which is contract of uniswap v3.

Comment: Seems like not the entire Uniswap library is on Sepolia: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/issues/560